# Algorithm to pack any small boxes into a big box

Tags: algorithms, combinatorics, efficiency, approximation, knapsack-problems

I have a container with a certain dimension. A number of small boxes that may be different in size is to be packed into the container. How to arrange the small boxes such that the container contains as many as possible?

- No rotation is allowed.
- The heavier boxes must not be on the top of the lighter ones.
- Approximation is allowed.

I am looking for the algorithm so I can implement it in a software.

Comment: Please give more information:  Have the boxes to be axis-aligned, or is it okay to rotate them. Are you interested in the computational complexity of the problem or in  algorithms or in both?

Comment: This is a NP-hard problem, and so exact solutions are possible only for small instances. Do you want approximation algorithms or heuristics or optimal (exact) algorithms only?

Comment: If you leave aside the criteria of heavier ones below lighter ones, this problem becomes the NP-hard 3D orthogonal knapsack problem, for which you can find approximation algorithms easily. Maybe you can get some hints for your specific case from that. Also, I believe a branch-and-bound based exact algorithm might also work for small inputs: as you have edited the question with the weight criteria, it might result in faster pruning/bounding of the search tree.

Comment: @Paresh is this variation known to be NP-hard?

Comment: @Bitwise I am not sure.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is called **3D Bin Packing** and is indeed an NP problem.

Looking those key words on Google will yield many articles about more or less complex approximation algorithms that can help you solve this problem.

Comment: May be this is good intuition on problem, but it's not an answer. At least provide some link in your answer, or explain how it's NP-Hard. Also OP was also interested in approximations.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is called [(multiple constraints) knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_knapsack_problems#Multiple_constraints) and is indeed an NP problem.

Looking those key words on Google will yield many articles about more or less complex approximation algorithms that can help you solve this problem :)